# "Брать" в смысле "покупать"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

В словарях "брать" в этом значении отмечено как разговорное. Но мне этого мало, чтобы понять, нормально для интеллигентного человека употреблять это слово в таком смысле или нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто понимает.

В "Служебном романе" есть вот такой диалог:

*— Вы купили новые сапоги, Вера?

— Да вот еще не решила, Людмила Прокофьевна. Вам нравятся?

— Очень вызывающие. Я бы такие не **взяла.** А на вашем месте интересовалась бы сапогами не во время работы, а после нее.

— Значит, хорошие сапоги, надо **брать.***

Неужели из-за того, что Людмила Прокофьевна и Вера так говорят, можно считать, что они малообразованные, не очень культурные?

Answer (score 1):

Это лексикон ушедшей эпохи т. н. дефицита, когда нужные людям товары лишь изредка появлялись в продаже. Деньги есть (цены на всё устойчивые), а купить нечего - нужно ждать, пока что-то появится, возможно, и впрок что-то купить. Тогда нужно было "брать" (пока "дают", "выкинули" в продажу), а то и хватать (пока не поздно). Т. е. в каком-то смысле "брали", а не покупали, "выкинутое" в продажу. Тогда так говорили практически все.

Comment: Да, логично, мне даже в голову не приходило! Но разве только в такой ситуации и в таких случаях так говорили, разве сейчас не говорят?

Comment: Может быть, кто-то по старой памяти так говорит или перенял от старших.

Comment: Да, я вот, видимо, перенял.)

Comment: Это выражение жаргонное, но вполне "культурное", ИМХО, и не обязательно связано с эпохой дефицита. Можете употреблять его не опасаясь за свою репутацию.

Comment: Надеюсь, что так и есть, ddbug, спасибо.)

Comment: По вашей логике, англичане берут поезд (take a train) из-за дефицита поездов.

Comment: Это не логика, а недавняя история. Англичане же не "берут" поезд, а садятся в него и едут: если по отдельным словам переводить с других языков, то китайцы пьют суп и никогда не едят его.

Comment: Как это англичане (и не только они, скандинавы тоже) не "берут" поезд, когда глагол "take" означает "взять"? Точно так же русские люди берут товары, отдавая за них деньги. И эпоха "т.н. дефицита" здесь не при чём.

Comment: Для правильного перевода безразлично, какое значение имеют отдельные слова или какими частями речи выражен один и тот же смысл - языки устроены по-разному. Даже начинающий переводчик это знает.

Answer (score 1):

> > В словарях "брать" в этом значении отмечено как разговорное. Но мне этого мало... Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто понимает.

Если вам мало словарей, то почему вам будет достаточно мнений простых любителей?

Comment: Просто я не знаю, как трактовать эту пометку!

Comment: Разговорное не знаете? Ну, вот, например, "наверняка" тоже помечено как разговорное.

Comment: А литературным разговорное разве не может быть? Вот хоть этот как раз пример взять (Ваше "наверняка").

Comment: Разговорное на то и разговорное, чтобы его употреблять в непринужденной устной речи. Наоборот, подчеркнутое избегание разговорных слов и выражений в устной речи может говорить о низковатой культуре.

Comment: Спасибо, в точку!

Answer (score 0):

Гоголь, "Вечера на хуторе близ Диканьки":

> – Чудно, право! А дай понюхать табаку. У тебя, кум, славный табак! Где ты **берешь** его?
>      – Кой черт, славный! - отвечал кум, закрывая березовую тавлинку, исколотую узорами. - Старая курица не чихнет!

Как видите, подобный оборот использовался ещё в 1832 году. Имеет смысл употреблять глагол "брать" вместо "покупать", чтобы сделать акцент на той вещи, которая "берётся", неважно – покупается ли она или нет.

Например, в разговоре можно услышать: "Я иду в гастроном, тебе взять что-нибудь?". Человек предлагает другому купить что-нибудь на обед, допустим, но факт покупки не важен, важно то, что человек принесет из гастронома то, что он там возьмёт (то есть купит).

Ничего плохого в использовании разговорных выражений в разговоре нет, на то они и разговорные. Такие обороты делают язык живым, богатым и выразительным.

Comment: В приведенном вами примере, по-моему, *брать* не равно *покупать*.

Comment: Конечно не равно! Но не исключает того, что табак покупался. В том-то и дело, что язык позволяет сместить акцент с покупки на приобретение, даже если это приобретение посредством покупки.

Comment: Здесь очевидное значение "достать". Где взял, где взял - купил!

Comment: 1862 год, словарь Даля. Статья "Брать" занимает около двух страниц, а слово "купить" в толкованиях не упоминается. Есть только упоминание о покупателе, который именно "берёт", и ясно почему - не заплатив сразу, по записи (в долг), на срок. http://www.booksite.ru/fulltext/dal/00/101.htm

Comment: Хотел сказать спасибо за пример, но не сообразил, ведь Александр действительно прав: здесь смысл "достаёшь". :( Но вообще мне Ваш ответ нравится.

Answer (score 0):

Даже не ожидал, что вопрос вызовет такой живой интерес. Попробую сделать второй заход :) У слова "брать" - несколько значений:

- Покупать. Происходит, видимо, от рынков. Продавцы кричали "подходи, **бери**!" а покупатели соответственно брали. Семантика: 1. товар имеется в изобилии (на**бирай**) 2. Есть выбор (вы**бирай**)
- **Брать** с боем, **взять** крепость, после продолжительных боёв наши войска **взяли** город Н-ск.
- **Взять** банк (ограбить). Семантика: ловко украсть и уйти безнаказанным.
- и можно наверно ещё что нибудь откопать.

В упомянутую "эпоху дефицита" шоппинг действительно мог напоминать взятие то ли крепости, то ли банка. В этом случае происходит коллизия нескольких семантических облаков, возможно, не осознаваемая самими говорящими. Это и придаёт "пикантность", жаргонность, которую вы уловили. Но значение "покупать" сейчас вполне самостоятельно и нейтрально.

Comment: Спасибо, ddbug!